# Ruby on Rails 4 render partial does not render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, partial

It has been months I try to upgrade an old Rails 2.X webpage to Rails 4.
I'm still struggling with some partial render views. So I thought I could use some help. I've saved all my [upgrade notes](http://tech.yipp.ca/ruby/upgrade-ruby-1-8-2-1-with-activerecord-4/) if it helps someone. But this one I cannot figure.

The current problem is that the following code prints only the address form (see the comment).

views/users/_seller.erb:

```
<table class="labels">
<tr>
  <td>{Seller type}</td>
  <td><%= seller.select(:stype, ["producer","distributor","store"]) %></td>
</tr>
(...)
<h3>{Store/Pickup address}</h3>
<% seller.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
<!-- THIS IS NOT RENDERED!! -->
<table class="labels">
<tr>
  <td>{Address Line 1}</td>
  <td><%= address_fields.text_field :line1 %></td>
</tr>
<!-- UP TO THERE IS NOT RENDERED!! -->
<% end %>
```

This partial view is called by this one:
views/users/create_seller.html.erb:

```
<h1>{Before you sell a product, please enter your seller information}</h1>

<%= form_for @seller, :url => "/seller/create" do |f| %>
  <h2>form</h2>
  <% @seller.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <p><%= msg %></p>
  <% end %>
  <%= render partial: "seller", locals: {seller:f} %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

If you need to see my model. I presume it is good because it was working in older version:
models/seller.rb

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :address, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => 'address_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true
  belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => 'shipping_address_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

This is the controller code

controllers/users_controllers.rb

```
def create_seller #get
  @user = @current_user
  @seller = Seller.new
  @seller.tax1 = 500
  @seller.tax1_name_fr = "TPS"
  @seller.tax1_name_en = "GST"
  @seller.tax2 = 950
  @seller.tax2_name_fr = "TVQ"
  @seller.tax2_name_en = "QST"
  @seller.build_address
  @seller.build_shipping_address
end
```

Comment: The partial does render, it's the fields_for that is not rendering, you should rename your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% seller.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
```

Should be

```
<%= seller.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
```

Note the "=" symbol after the `<%` to show output I'm sure you already realise this but using the = sign in erb tags was a major change after version 2.xx

Comment: I had realized for <% form_for ... %>, but never thought about <% object.fields_for ... %>. Thanks again!!